# How to add items in the bibliography using Classic Thesis?

Tags: bibtex, classicthesis

I am writing my thesis using classic thesis. When I try to add some items in the file `Bibliography.bib` and then compile, the new items doesn't appear in the PDF file. Why? How can I solve it?

The `.blg` file says:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: ClassicThesis.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/DirtyTitlepage.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Titlepage.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Titleback.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Dedication.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Abstract.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Publications.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Acknowledgments.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Contents.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter01.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter02.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter03.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter0A.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Bibliography.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Declaration.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: FrontBackmatter/Colophon.aux
Reallocated glb_str_ptr (elt_size=4) to 20 items from 10.
Reallocated global_strs (elt_size=20001) to 20 items from 10.
Reallocated glb_str_end (elt_size=4) to 20 items from 10.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 6000 items from 3000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
Database file #1: ClassicThesis-blx.bib
Database file #2: Bibliography.bib
Database file #3: AMiede_Publications.bib
Biblatex version: 3.8
Reallocated wiz_functions (elt_size=4) to 9000 items from 6000.
Reallocated singl_function (elt_size=4) to 100 items from 50.
You've used 27 entries,
            6268 wiz_defined-function locations,
            1327 strings with 11696 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 134242 in all, are:
= -- 9321
> -- 3027
< -- 1428
+ -- 2570
- -- 690
* -- 7813
:= -- 10262
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 27
change.case$ -- 26
chr.to.int$ -- 30
cite$ -- 52
duplicate$ -- 14215
empty$ -- 12789
format.name$ -- 1367
if$ -- 29895
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 114
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 723
num.names$ -- 2042
pop$ -- 8569
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 1143
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 7515
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 13129
swap$ -- 4042
text.length$ -- 655
text.prefix$ -- 26
top$ -- 1
type$ -- 906
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 1167
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 697
```

I think it uses `biblatex`, because in the config file I found this:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
%backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
language=auto,%
style=numeric-comp,%
%style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
%bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author 
with ---
sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
%backref=true,%
natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
%backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
language=auto,%
style=numeric-comp,%
%style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
%bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author 
with 
---
sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
maxbibnames=15, % default: 3, et al.
%backref=true,%
natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource[label=ownpubs]{AMiede_Publications.bib}
\begin{document}
This is a citation \cite{bentley:1999}
Here is the bibliography
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
\phantomsection
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{#1}}%
\chapter*{#1}%
}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

This doesn't print the bibliography, but gives no errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you recompile the bibliography with bibtex/biber?

Comment: Yes, with bibtex!

Comment: What does the .blg file say?

Comment: Should i paste all the text contained in the file here?

Comment: It's not a very long file?

Comment: I cannot paste it here as a comment.

Comment: You can edit your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Done!

Comment: There seems to be nothing special (as far as I can say). Did you cite the new items?

Comment: Yes. But they don't work. The old ones do work.

Comment: Just in case: delete all auxilliary files (including .blg, .bbl, &c.) and follow the whole cycle again.

Comment: Which are the other auxiliary files (.blg,.bl excluded)? I tried with these two but it doesn't work.

Comment: .aux, .bcf, .run.xml – I believe that's all.

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't work...

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` or ordinary `bibtex`? Please provide a full [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: @DavidPurton I updated my answer. I don't know how to write a MWEB, because i am using this https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis. I haven't modified anything about bibliography. I just tried to add an item in the file .bib but if i compile, the new item doesn't apper. I don't understand why, since if i modify the items already in the file .bib, they can be updated!

Comment: @ciccio, without an example it's very hard to help you. Can you get *anything* working with `biblatex` based on the link in my previous comment? Just use `article` class and forget about `classicthesis` and all your packages for the moment. Then make sure you are running `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Just use your `biblatex` set up for the testing.

Comment: Notice this line: backend=bibtex8, bibencoding=ascii. It says: use bibtex8 (not bibtex, not biber) and your bib file should be saved as plain ascii (not utf-8, not latin-2 etc). Check how the text editor saves your bib file. Biber is a much better option, have you tried if it's working?

Comment: Also, it's not enough to just add a reference to the bib file. You have to add a citation to it in any of the chapter tex files.

Comment: @DavidPurton I have put an example.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip i tried to put biber instead of bibtex8, but it gives me : i found no \citation commands---while reading file ClassicThesis.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ClassiThesis.aux I founf no \bibstyle command---while reafding file ClassicThesis.aux (There were 3 error messages). Moreover i tried tu put a citation, but it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Start with the last example in your question and add a `\cite` to an entry in `Bibliography.bib` (or even better, add `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` and `\cite{sigfridsson}`). Start over in a new, empty directory or clean at least all temporary files like `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`. Compile the TeX document with LaTeX. If there are any errors or warnings, fix them as far as possible. Not all warning can be fixed immediately (like ones about missing references), but there must not be any errors. Then run BibTeX. Then run LaTeX twice more. Report all remaining errors and warnings.

Comment: @moewe: i did as you told me. It gives me this warnings: 1)Using fall-back BibTex(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavaible. 2) Citation 'bertram' on page 1 undefined. 3) Empty bibliography. 4) There were undefined references. 5) Please (re)run BibTex on the file(s):(biblatex) Bibliography(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Comment: Warning 1 can be ignored, though of course Biber is the preferred backend. Number 2-5 (jointly) suggest that you either did not run BibTeX or that the BibTeX run failed. What does the `.blg` say?

Comment: @moewe: I couldn't open database file Bibliography.bib
---line 3 of file Bibliography.aux
 : \bibdata{Bibliography-blx,Bibliography
 :                                       ,AMiede_Publications,biblatex-examples}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command

Comment: Database file #1: Bibliography-blx.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "sigfridsson"

Comment: Do you have a file called `Bibliography.bib` in the same directory as your `.tex` file? For the time being remove all `\addbibresource` instructions except for the one reading `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` and only cite the entry `sigfridsson` (which is contained in `biblatex-examples.bib`). Re-compile with the full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle.

Comment: @moewe yes, i have. I did what you told me, but it gives me exactly the same warnings.

Comment: If you have removed all `\addbibresource`s except the one reading `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`, clean all the auxiliary files and run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX the `.blg` file will not complain about `Bibliography.bib`. That should normally even be the case if you don't delete the auxiliary files. So if you followed the suggestions the error message in the `.blg` should be different now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90837/discussion-between-moewe-and-ciccio).